# WPF grid: set style for focused row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a simple WPF grid as an example, with each row having the same height (*). Each of three rows has a single textbox inside. I would like to know if it's possible, in XAML, to specify that when the textbox gets focus, the relevant row should increase to 2* (thus increasing the size for the textbox).

Thanks...

-Ben

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"                       
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0" />
      <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="1" />
      <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="2" />
   </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the in the Style value for `Grid.Row` using `Trigger` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But to place all the elements in `Grid` necessary to set a value for `Grid.Row` locally. In this case, given the [`Dependency Property Value Precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we have in the Style values that will be ignored.

I recommend you just set the `Height` for the `TextBox`, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Grid.Row="0" /> 
    <TextBox Name="TextBox2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Name="TextBox3" Grid.Row="2" /> 
</Grid>
```

Or hide/show `TextBox` via EventTriggers depending on the focus. To do this you just for each `TextBox` to create a `EventTrigger` with `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events. For more information, please see this:

[`MSDN: EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Anatoliy, regarding the first suggestion, wouldn't that change the value of "grid.row" on the textbox itself? meaning, wouldn't it move the textbox to a different grid row, rather than affect the size of the relevant row?

Comment: @BenjiFB: Yes, it will change the value for the current `TextBox`. It seems easier to change the Height directly for each controls, or use `EventTriggers` with focus events.

Comment: > or use EventTriggers with focus events   - Would I still need to adjust the size of the textbox itself, or could I use an EventTrigger to adjust the size of the containing row?

Comment: @BenjiFB: Most likely will only set the size, I tried to set values for `Grid.Row` in `EventTrigger`, but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to make the font size bigger when any textblock gets focus? If yes then here's one way to do it

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not quite. As is, each textbox takes an equal portion (33.3%) of the window. I want it such that when a user clicks in a textbox, it takes a bigger portion (50%, with 25% + 25% for the other two boxes). So to move from (* * *) to (* 2* *) when something is clicked.